# Compile Error: Argument not optional error when I call macro from other macro

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, macros, vba

I have a button that when pressed calls some Macros to be done. 
All my macros are running fine with Exception of the “AddDropDown“ Macro. 
It keeps giving me an error that says “Compile Error: Argument not optional (Error 449)”.

These run fine if I manually just select them and press Run.

The help page says “The number and types of arguments must match those expected. This error has the following causes and solutions:
•   Incorrect number of arguments. Supply all necessary arguments. For example, the Left function requires two arguments; the first representing the character string being operated on, and the second representing the number of characters to return from the left side of the string. Because neither argument is optional, both must be supplied.
•   Omitted argument isn't optional. An argument can only be omitted from a call to a user-defined procedure if it was declared Optional in the procedure declaration. Either supply the argument in the call or declare the parameter Optional in the definition.”

My code is something like this:

```
    Private Sub Button_Click()
        Macro1
        Macro2
        AddDropDowns
        AddDropDown
        Macro3
    End Sub
```

And the Macro that gives the error is the one below:

```
Sub AddDropDowns()
Dim cell As Range
Dim iDropDown As Long

With Worksheets("SourceSheet")
    For Each cell In .Range("B13", .Cells(13,     .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        AddDropDownEnroll Worksheets("DropDownsSheet"), iDropDown, cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address 
    Next cell
End With
End Sub


Sub AddDropDown(sht As Worksheet, dropDownCounter As Long, header As String, validationFormula As String)
With sht.Range("A1").Offset(, dropDownCounter) '<--| reference passed sheet row 1 passed column
    .Cells(1, 1) = header '<--| write header
    With .Cells(2, 1).Validation '<--| reference 'Validation' property of cell 1 row below currently referenced one
        .Delete            
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
dropDownCounter = dropDownCounter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you read the code you copy/paste? You're calling `AddDropDown` with no arguments, and it's clearly written to require 4 (a worksheet, a long, and two strings).

Comment: Yes, the help page is exactly correct.  `The number and types of arguments must match those expected.`  You have called it with no parameters (`AddDropDown`), and it is expecting 4 values (`Sub AddDropDown(sht As Worksheet, dropDownCounter As Long, header As String, validationFormula As String)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Sub Button_Click()`, change:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Macro1
    Macro2
    AddDropDowns
    AddDropDown
    Macro3
End Sub
```

into:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Macro1
    Macro2
    AddDropDowns
    Macro3
End Sub
```

In `AddDropDowns()`, change:

```
AddDropDownEnroll Worksheets("DropDownsSheet"), iDropDown, cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address
```

into:

```
AddDropDown Worksheets("DropDownsSheet"), iDropDown, cell.Offset(-1).Value, "='" & .Name & "'!" & cell.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.EntireColumn) - 1).Address
```

Comment: Would the _brave_ downvoter show up and give any explanation so as to both have people know why they shouldn't follow thi answer and teach me how to improve it?